# How to delete subject from cluster role binding in GKE using Cloud Shell

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a `ClusterRole`:

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: restricted-pods-role
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - podsecuritypolicies
  resourceNames:
  - restricted-psp
  verbs:
  - use
```

I have given `cluster-admin` privileges to user account `alex.pitt@xcom.net` through the `ClusterRoleBinding` using below command:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole cluster-admin --user alex.pitt@xcom.net
```

Now I want to give the same cluster-admin privileged to dave.pot@xcom.net instead of alex.pitt@xcom.net.

How can I do it from Cloud Shell?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to give the same cluster-admin privileged to dave.pot@xcom.net instead of alex.pitt@xcom.net.
>   How can I do it from Cloud Shell?

- You can do it in a single command from cloud shell with `kubectl patch`. Copy the command and replace `newuser@domain.com` with the desired user:

```
kubectl patch clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding -p '{"subjects":[{"apiGroup":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io","kind":"User","name":"newuser@domain.com"}]}'
```

- Or you can edit the manifest using the default text editor (usually vi) on-flight using:

`kubectl edit clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding`

---

One thing that I'd like to comment:

- I noticed you created a cluster role called `restricted-pods-role` and on the second part you are assigning the role `cluster-admin` to the user, which gives full control over the cluster.
- You made it reasonably clear in the question that this was your intention, but in case what you want to achieve is to assign the just created role to the user, the command would be:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding restricted-pods-binding --clusterrole restricted-pods-role --user someuser@domain.com
```

- It's worth mentioning that a [Cluster Role Binding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) grants the permissions defined in a ClusterRole to a user **or a set of users.** It holds a list of subjects (users, groups, or service accounts), so you can use the same Binding to multiple users.

---

**Reproduction:**

- I deployed the `ClusterRoleBinding` as in your example:

```
$ k get clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding -o yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-05-12T14:55:14Z"
  name: cluster-admin-binding
  resourceVersion: "48399"
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterrolebindings/cluster-admin-binding
  uid: 7a5055e3-e464-405c-9ed2-891eb671a948
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: alex.pitt@xcom.net
```

- And applied the patch as instructed above:

```
$ kubectl patch clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding -p '{"subjects":[{"apiGroup":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io","kind":"User","name":"newuser@domain.com"}]}'
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/cluster-admin-binding patched

$ k get clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding -o yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-05-12T14:55:14Z"
  name: cluster-admin-binding
  resourceVersion: "49703"
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterrolebindings/cluster-admin-binding
  uid: 7a5055e3-e464-405c-9ed2-891eb671a948
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: newuser@domain.com
```

As you can see the user were replaced.

If you still have any questions regarding this procedure let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes you are right that I have created a Cluster role as restricted-pods-role with resource as podsecuritypolicy named restricted-psp but while creating Clusterrolebinding I have given cluster-admin role just for test. But my intention to know how to change the subject in clusterrole binding.

Comment: I have another confusion about the Role/Clusterrole,  Rolebinding/Clusterrolebinding and Subject sequence. If I am not wrong below is sequence
1. First we create Role/Clusterrole
2. Add the subject and Role/Clusterrole to Rolebinding/Clusterrolebinding.
Kindly correct me if I am wrong or add if I am missing anything.. It would be great..

Comment: I see, that's why I decided to give you both alternatives. Regarding your second comment: A Role/RoleBinding is used to give permissions in a specific namespace, whereas ClusterRole/ClusterRoleBinding is used to give permissions that are applied on Cluster level, giving access to all namespaces. Subject is the user/group/serviceaccount that will be granted the permissions.